# Getting gitlab-runner 10.0.2 cloning repo using ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab installation and I am trying to setup a gitlab-runner using a docker executor. All ok until tests start running and then since my projects are private and they have no http access enabled, they fail at clone time with:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.0.2 (a9a76a50)
  on Jupiter-docker (5f4ed288)
Using Docker executor with image fedora:26 ...
Using docker image sha256:1f082f05a7fc20f99a4ccffc0484f45e6227984940f2c57d8617187b44fd5c46 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image fedora:26 ...
Using docker image fedora:26 ID=sha256:b0b140824a486ccc0f7968f3c6ceb6982b4b77e82ef8b4faaf2806049fc266df for build container...
Running on runner-5f4ed288-project-5-concurrent-0 via 2705e39bc3d7...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/pmatos/tob'...
remote: Git access over HTTP is not allowed
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.linki.tools/pmatos/tob.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have looked into https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html 
and decided to give it a try so my `.gitlab-ci.yml` starts with:

```
image: fedora:26

before_script:
  # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  # For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
  # you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
  # WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
  # you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

... JOBS...
```

I setup the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY correctly, etc but the issue is that the cloning of the project happens before `before_script`. I then tried to start the container with `-v /home/pmatos/gitlab-runner_ssh:/root/.ssh` but still the cloning is trying to use `HTTP`. How can I force the container to clone through ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way gitlab CI works, CI requires `https` access to the repository. Therefore if you enable CI, you need to have `https` repo access enabled as well.

This is however, not an issue privacy wise as making the container `https` accessible doesn't stop gitlab from checking if you're authorized to access it.

Comment: OK, this seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

> I then tried to start the container with -v /home/pmatos/gitlab-runner_ssh:/root/.ssh but still the cloning is trying to use HTTP

Try at least if possible within your container to add a

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@.insteadOf https://
```

(assuming the ssh user is `git`)

That would make any clone of any https URL use ssh.

Comment: That's not possible unfortunately because the container is created a new each time `gitlab-runner` starts a new pipeline build.